# How do I configure the IntelliJ HQL Console to work with Spring Boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-boot, hql

I'm using Spring Boot and IntelliJ. Because Spring Boot auto-configures the database, there is no hibernate.cfg.xml file. Typically, when you want to execute HQL queries on the console, you connect via this configuration file.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-the-hibernate-console.html#d951572e120

Unfortunately, I don't have that file as an entry point. How else can I execute HQL queries?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: why dont create hibernate.cfg.xml in resource directory ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34178331/intellij-how-to-correctly-configure-hql-with-spring-boot-now-i-get-persistence

Answer (score 2):

You should have your entityManagerFactory registered and then in persistence tab right-click on entityManagerFactory an choose Console. (I'm using Intellij EAP 2018.1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just only execute some commands on your database, you just need to create a new file named "**data.sql**" under **resources** directory and you can write your all queries inside this file. They all will be executed while spring boot application starts.