# Intellij how to correctly configure hql with spring boot. Now i get Persistence QL Queries are error-checked

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

So i was trying to use a custom query using hibernate and jpa

```
@Transactional
public interface EstimateOptionsDao extends JpaRepository<EstimateOptions, Integer> {

    @Query("from estimateOptions options inner join options.company company inner join company.user user where user.name = :userName\n")
    EstimateOptions EstimateOptions(String userName);

}
```

But the `EstimateOptions` gives me the following error:

```
Can't resolve symbol 'EstimateOptions' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked
```

So i found this post [Why does Hibernate query have compile error in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188186/why-does-hibernate-query-have-compile-error-in-intellij).

So i added a facet to test this:

Now i have hibernate.cfg.xml like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url"/>
    <property name="connection.driver_class"/>
    <property name="connection.username"/>
    <property name="connection.password"/>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And spring configuration like this :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

But if i got to the Persistence Tool in intellij en do a simple query like this:

hql> From user

it produce the following error:

```
[2015-12-09 12:59:27] org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class []
[2015-12-09 12:59:27] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
.....
```

As you can see i'm a bit lost... What is wrong with these settings ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In `Project structure` settings (ctrl+alt+shift+s), select `Facets` and `Add`.
2. Select `JPA`
3. Select the module containing your mappings/annotated entities
4. In the `Modules` view, select the module in question and the `JPA` facet underneath
5. Add a reference to your descriptor (persistence.xml/orm.xml)
6. Select your JPA provider from the dropdown

Your JPA-queries should then be validated against your entites.

Comment: Thanks i have been struggling the whole day with this. But you really saved me ;)

Comment: I've configured my hibernate with spring mvc in annotation based configuration. But only .xml format descriptor can be added to the JPA facet. How to do the above procedure with annotation based hibernate configuration ?

Comment: You don't have any xml files, not even one stating where to look for the annotation based configuration?

Comment: what about the JPA Default provider dropdown?

Comment: Same issue here, it seems that if you do not have any descriptors or beans defined in your project (but leave the spring-boot do the job) intelliJ does not perform validation over your HQL queries