# JpaRepository database connection error on @query the table showing red

Tags: java, spring-boot

Help me masters...
i keep got error Cant resolve symbol on my JpaRepository
Query @Query(value="SELECT i FROM AkunIpaddressEnt i ORDER BY i.ID DESC")

the word "AkunIpaddressEnt" query my query showing red iam sure everything is on the right place, am using intelij spring-boot JpaRepository

my repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional("dbilapTransactionManager")
public interface AkunIpaddressRepo extends JpaRepository<AkunIpaddressEnt,Integer> {
    @Query(value="SELECT i FROM AkunIpaddressEnt i ORDER BY i.ID DESC")
    List<AkunIpaddressEnt> getlistIPaddress();
}
```

my entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="AKUN_IPADDRESS")
public class AkunIpaddressEnt {
@Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AKUNIPADRESSSEQUENCE")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "AKUNIPADRESSSEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, name = "AKUNIPADRESSSEQUENCE")
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

my configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.repository.dbilap",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbilapEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "dbilapTransactionManager")
public class DbConDBILAP {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource DbilapDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("datasource2.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource2.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("datasource2.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("datasource2.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbilapEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(DbilapDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(
                new String[] { "com.entity.dbilap" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("datasource2.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("show.sql",
                env.getProperty("datasource2.hibernate.show.sql"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbilapTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                dbilapEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }


}
```

my properties

```
datasource2.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@0.0.0.0:1521:DBILAP
datasource2.username=MYUSERNAME
datasource2.password=MYPASSWORD
datasource2.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
datasource2.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle8iDialect
datasource2.hibernate.show.sql=true
```

whats wrong?

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace to share or a complete compilation error message?

Answer (score 0):

Queries in Spring Data should reference entity name and property names, instead of table name and column names.

So, your query should be:

```
@Query(value="SELECT i FROM AkunIpaddressEnt i ORDER BY i.id DESC")
```

Instead of:

```
@Query(value="SELECT i FROM AKUN_IPADDRESS i ORDER BY i.ID DESC")
```

Also remove the (name="dbilapEntityManager") of your Entity because you are overriding the entity name expected in the queries with a name that is not related with the entity itself.

Finally in the @Table you should use the "name" attribute instead of the "schema" attribute to define the table name.

Comment: Can't resolve symbol 'AkunIpaddressEnt'
 This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the IntelliJ IDEA configuration, not with the query itself. Cannot help with that, as I use Eclipse. Check this answer that maybe of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178738/3993742